# How to edit role-user after I added the role to the user by usermanager addtorole?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am a self learning computer programming and now I am learning ASP.NET Core. In my first ASP.NET Core application I have created roles and users, then I have added a user to a role using `userManager.addtorole`. Now I want to replace the role that I added to the user with another role, for example:
I created a user with email user@yahoo.com and a role with name role1
I used `usermanager.addtorole(role1)`
Everything is good.
I want to enable the administrator of the application to edit the user-role by replacing role 1 with another role.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method that removes a specified role from the user which was added to the role.
I have tested the method it works very good, after removing the user from the role i could add a new role to the user.
I have found the method by browsing the code intellisense of the userManager object, her is the code:

```
public void Test(ApplicationUser user1, ApplicationRole role1, 
  ApplicationRole role2)
{
  UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

  await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user1, role1.Name);

  // Remove user1 from role1.
  await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user1, role1.Name);

  // add user1 to role2.
  await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user1, role2.Name);
}
```

Very simple.